# re.sub not matching nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

with the following dict:

```
interfaces = {'A':{'568':'A1','590':'A2'},'B':{'590':'B2'}}
```

i what to replace the value='590' with A2 while setting the A element and B2 while setting the B element.

I've tried :

```
pattern_interfaces = r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(sorted(re.escape(k) for k in interfaces['A']))) #=>(568|590)

re_value = re.sub(pattern_interfaces, lambda m: interfaces.get(m.group(0).upper()), value, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

but `re_value` is blank.

Can anyone explain why is that.

Thx.

[update]

ok , i see where i was wrong lambda m: interfaces['A'] does what i needed.

Comment: The description is quite vague. I wonder why you're using `re`  to mutate a dictionary. Please show your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You matched keys from `interfaces['A']`, not from `interfaces`. Use that nested dictionary if you are going to generate a regex from that keys :

```
re_value = re.sub(
    pattern_interfaces,
    lambda m: interfaces['A'][m.group(0).upper()],
    value, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

I replaced the `dict.get()` call with direct subscription; you can only match existing keys with your regex, no need to account for missing keys here.

Your sample also matched numbers, not letters, so neither the `.upper()` call nor the `re.IGNORECASE` will make a difference here.